# Yii2 validation, allow few different formats

Tags: php, validation, activerecord, yii2

I want to allow multiple formats for a field in `Yii2` `ActiveRecord` like:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['date', 'date', 'format' => 'php:Y-m-d H:i'],
        ['date', 'date', 'format' => 'php:Y-m-d'],
    ];
}
```

But like this it fails if any of them fails. I there any way to do it `rules`?

Currently I'm thinking of doing it in `beforeValidate` like:

```
public function beforeValidate()
{
    $this->date = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($this->date));
    return parent::beforeValidate();
}
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: what is the field type in your database, i mean you are using a field of type text? and you want to just allow the desired formats to be saved in the database and want to control it on model level

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam field type is date

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by making function, for example `validateDateFormat()` and to handle logic inside it, and then in rules you say `['date', 'validateDateFormat']`, refer to Yii's documentation for more informations.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Custom Rule it work like this .

Just add under rule

```
['date','datefunction']

public function datefunction($attribute,$params){
  $date      =   $this->$attribute;
/*****check validation******/

 $this->addError($attribute, "Date : $date  Format is wrong");
}
```

Note: Your may get DB exception error. You need to change format once saving a file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to match multiple date and time formats? Try this way:

```
['date', 'match', 'pattern' => '#^(?!0000)[0-9]{4}-((0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(0[13-9]|1[0-2])-(29|30)|(0[13578]|1[02])-31)( ([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]))?$#']
```